# How to delimit this text file? strtok

Tags: c++

so there's a text file where I have 1. languages, a 2. text of a number written in the said language, 3. the base of the number and 4. the number written in digits. Here's a sample:

```
francais                deux mille quatre cents         10 2400
```

How I went about it:

```
struct Nomen{
char langue[21], nomNombre [31], baseC[3], nombreC[21];
int base, nombre;
};
```

and in the main:

```
if(myfile.is_open()){
    {
    while(getline(myfile, line))
    {
        strcpy(Linguo[i].langue, strtok((char *)line.c_str(), "  "));
        strcpy(Linguo[i].nomNombre, strtok(NULL, "  "));
        strcpy(Linguo[i].baseC, strtok(NULL, "  "));
        strcpy(Linguo[i].nombreC, strtok(NULL, "\n"));


        i++;
    }
```

Difficulty: I'm trying to put two whitespaces as a delimiter, but it seems that strtok() counts it as if there were only one whitespace. The fact there are spaces in the text number, etc. is messing up the tokenization. How should I go about it?

Comment: `.c_str()` - you're writing C++, then why do you use all these C functions?

Comment: Ditto for `strcpy()`. Furthermore, this is what the C library's `strtok` does: skip over consecutive delimiters. If you don't want to do it, you can't use `strtok`.

Comment: Because strtok only takes c strings. So how should I go about assigning these text informations to the different structure arrays?

Comment: Also you **cannot** / must not *`strtok`* `std::string.c_str()`. It modifies the string. How did you come up with this idea? Since this seems to be a C++ question I am removing the C tag.

Comment: There is absolutely no need for `strtok`.  Why are you not simply using `>>` to read the input into the separate variables?

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` treats any single character in the provided string as a delimiter. It does not treat the string itself as a single delimiter. So `"  "` (two spaces) is the same as `" "` (one space).

`strtok` will also treat multiple delimiters together as a single delimiter. So the input `"t1     t2"` will be tokenized as two tokens, `"t1"` and `"t2"`.

As mentioned in comments, `strtok` is also writes the `NUL` character into the input to create the token strings. So, it is an error to pass the result of `string::c_str()` as input to the function. The fact that you need to cast the constant string should have been enough to dissuade you from this approach.

If you want to treat a double space as a delimiter, you will have to scan the string and search for them yourself. Given you are using C APIs, you can consider `strstr`. However, in C++, you can use `string::find`.

Here's an algorithm to parse your string manually:

Given an input string `input`:

- `language` is the substring from the start of `input` to the first SPC character.
- From where `language` ends, skip over all whitespace, changing `input` to begin at the first non-whitespace character.
- `text` is the substring from the start of `input` to the first double SPC sequence.
- From where `text` ends, skip over all whitespace, changing `input` to begin at the first non-whitespace character.
- Parse `base`, and parse `number`.

Comment: So how can I tokenize the aforementioned line into the different structure variables?